# How many separate apps should I have with my Django app

Tags: django, django-templates, django-apps

How many apps should I have in my Django project. For instance, I am building a pet application where there can be owners, pets, veterinarians, etc.

For now sticking to only the 3 I mentioned should I have these as separate apps within my Django project or should I just create one app to handle everything. I will be adding more features as time goes on.

The idea I had was to create a project

`django-admin startproject mypets`

Then create an application for each:

`python manage.py startapp pet`

and

`python manage.py startapp pet_owner`

and

`python manage.py startapp veterianarian`

As I mentioned before, there are other features I will be adding to my application like photos todo like feature and so on. My concern is that my project is going to get big which is why I want to separate `pet_owner` and `pet` each as their own apps. I was thinking this is exactly what I should do but then realized that when I went to `mypets.urls.py` file and I was thinking about forwarding some requests to a path I quickly realized that I want my route to always have `mypets/`.

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('mypets/petowner/', include('petowner.urls')),
    path('mypets/pet/', include('pet.urls')),
]
```

but they seem separate in a way that I do not want them to be. For instance. I care about having `mypets/petowner/<petowner-id>/pets/` etc. They are going to be very closely related to each other and I will be using relationships in my `models`. The separation that I want is mostly for organization and readability. I do not want to have a file `models.py` with a huge amount of code - I think that is ugly and messy.

I plan in the future to use `React` for my frontend, but because I'm trying to learn Django well I'm going to stick to a full Django app and use `django-templates`. Not sure if this matters but thought I would mention it just in case.

Answer (score 0):

that is good idea and make project more organized specially for you
if you want to develope your code in the future this works and good for you
if you have problem with urls, now i have a suggestion, you can make a file like `url.py` in your app which contains your apps urls and then you can back to your main url and give it to urls it seems you know this way

1. first run your app and make it
2. now got to app folde  and make a file like `urls.py`
3. now into that you can write your urls and write your urls in urlpattern as you know
4. before finish make sure that in the main `url.py` you have to include other urls that made

```
    urlpatterns = [
       path('', include('petowner.urls')),
       path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    ]
```

maybe this is good to change your names if involve you too much and write your urls in that app by this way you can be more organized and give your prefix or anything just in your `app/urls.py`

Comment: Thanks for the response. I was wondering if because `pet_owner` and `pet` are closely related and neither exist without the other, `pet_owner` can but doesn't do much without a `pet`, then I expand my application to include `veterinary hospitals`, `vets`, `appointments`, so on. I see this as standing alone as its own application. So maybe something like `pets` can be an app and `local_hospitals` can be another app and so on. So I wouldn't be separating every thing but separating apps that truly do not have anything to do with the other. But of course I will connect these to work together.

Comment: your welcome I hope this response was helpfull for you, im totally agree by app you can do it much readable and everything goes safe and dandy.